# need to show HTML in jsp using struts tagLib

Tags: java, struts

I am working on a `Java (Struts)` based web application. I have to show some content by getting from DB in jsp. Example content:

```
<div>
some code here
<a> link here</>
</div>
```

I am using `textarea` for the time but when I put this into `textarea` using following tag:

```
<html:textarea property = "contentFromDB" rows = "12" cols = "70"  styleClass = "textarea" disabled="true"/>
```

It shows the HTML in the textarea, is there any way I may show the content in the `textarea` with out HTML tags or I may show the content in any other tag like `P` or `span`, I cannot find these tags in the struts tagLib as well.

Comment: If you want to show your HTML in the textarea you have to add the attribute `contentEditable="true"`, BUT, this only works with HTML5 browsers.

Comment: no, not good for me, also my application is IE specific

Comment: It is not necessary that i have to show content in textarea, i just need to show the content in the page, container is optional, i can use simple div, p or span as well, but i don't know how to show content in these tags using struts taglib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<html:xxx>` tags are for forms.

The best practice is to use JSTL's `<c:out>` with an appropriately-scoped object (e.g., a request attribute) and set `escape` to false:

```
<c:out value="xxx" escapeXml="false" />
```

Alternatively if you're on an antiquated container or just have nothing better to do, [use the `<bean:write>` tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-bean.html#write). I don't recall its escaping behavior(s), if any.